# Lenovo Y50-70 Hard Drive Locked After BIOS change

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, passwords

I went into my BIOS and wanted to play with some security functions. I added a password for system boot, master password, and user password. All having identical passwords. I save and restart, then pops up the system password prompt. I enter and bypass, then comes another prompt which was weird to me. I enter the same password since I only entered one password. No access. What's locked is my harddrive. This is a laptop by the way.

I tried typing in different combinations (just in case I fat fingered) but no luck. I spent a lot of time on it even though after two failed attempts, you have to restart. I removed the hard drive and made it into an external drive and tried to see if  I could reformat the drive but it is in a state where it's not accessible (I believe due to the password). I've tried through linux (gparted and parted) and windows tools (disk manager, chkdsk, and others can't remember right now) but they all give me an input/output error--not able to read the drive. Something to note is that the computer recognizes the drive but doesn't display the partitions. It just says it's unallocated and not initilized. I cannot partition the drive, nor can I initialize it because it cannot access it. I tried booting my computer from a fresh USB win10 install to see if I could format the drive that way but I kept getting the error that I could not install windows via USB. Something to point out is that every other computer will recognize the harddrive externally but the main laptop I pulled it from will not recognize it as an external drive (not in boot menu and it just stays on the lenovo boot screen FOREVER). I did try contacting Lenovo support to see what they could do over the phone but unfortunately the man said there was nothing that could be done, possibly Microsoft could assist. I called to check if there was a default hard drive password or something. But no luck. If anyone wants the hard drive model, just let me know, I have to put it back in the laptop to figure that out, but I know it's WD. Thank you for your suggestions and help. If you have any more questions or requests, feel free to ask.

*PS - didn't upgrade anything. All components are default.
*PSS - I don't care about wiping the drive, I just want to be able to use it again.
*PSSS - If you are wondering if it's encrypted, I wouldn't be able to tell you. All I did was enter a password before this issue occurred..

EDITED PIC of similar screen (not mine got from http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/t/19580547)

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ0RC.png)
[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqJbY.png)

Comment: Microsoft cannot help you with Lenovo hardware.  Have you tried to remove the passwords you set? You have a HDD or a SSD?

Comment: SSHD - hybrid..

Comment: Possibly an [ATA password](https://www.rockbox.org/lock.html)? I would suggest first trying both upper and lower case versions of the password you just set, and if that doesn't work then search for any known default ATA password for your drive model/manufacturer.

Comment: I thought about the upper/lower option and tried it. Turns out when I entered my system password in uppercase, it still let me access the system (even though I typed it lower case). So, I can only assume upper/lower doesn't matter. For clarity, the problem is not solved, I was talking about the system password, not the hard disk password. 

FYI, I took it to a local tech, and they were unable to fix the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you may have had windows/lenovo/bitlocker encryption on the drive. when you made major changes to the bios, the system detected that as an intrusion and locked the drive for security, seen it a few times.

when i have dealt with this problem in the past it was specifically bitlocker and i was lucky the customer (corporate client) had the windows bitlocker password on hand to bypass.

there are posts online saying that you can contact microsoft to get access to the encryption password, but my experience says otherwise.

but you may have more luck than i.

> Places to look for your BitLocker key:
>
> - On a printout you saved. Look in places you keep important papers.
> - Saved on a USB flash drive. Plug the USB flash drive in to your locked PC and follow the instructions. If you saved the key as a text file on the flash drive, use a different computer to read the text file.
> - In your Microsoft account. To get your recovery key, go to BitLocker Recovery Keys.
> - In your Azure Active Directory account. For work PCs where you sign in with an Azure Active Directory account, to get your recovery key, see the device info for your Microsoft Azure account.
>
>   Or ask someone for help:
> - Ask someone with administrator privileges on the same PC to unlock it with their key.
> - If your PC is connected to a domain (usually a work or school computer), ask a system administrator for your recovery key.
>
>   If you still can't get in, you'll need to reset your PC. Learn how.

Bitlocker Source:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4026181/windows-find-my-bitlocker-recovery-key

Comment: That sounds promising... However, I have windows 10 HOME. From my previous research (because I wanted to set up bitlocker in the past), the home version does not come with bitlocker features. I looked on my associated microsoft account and I have no bit locker keys. Thanks though.

Comment: i have in fact seen bitlocker on a win 10 home pc, was also a lenovo. food for thought. sorry i couldn't help

Comment: Bitlocker full disk encryption cannot be enable on a Windows 10 but device encryption can be which is typically reserved for tablets.  Device encryption works differently than Bitlocker it doesn’t behave the same way to changes and you would know if you enabled it.  Since your local account was linked to a MS account your recovery keys would be linked, if there are no recovery keys, then you didn’t have device encryption enabled at any point.

Comment: I'm pretty confident it's not bitlocker considering there isn't a windows looking interface. I wanted to upload a pic but had some issues connecting my phone to Linux.. It's not reading the files. But anyway.. Here's a link to a pic of a similar looking screen that I see located in the above OP